# How to differentiate between an atof of a character vs an input of zero

Tags: c

`atof()` returns `0.0` if it its argument cannot be parsed as a valid float.

How do I differentiate that from when it is given an actual `0`?

Comment: You cannot. So use `strtof/strtod`.

Comment: While the duplicate mentions `atoi` and the corresponding `strtol`, there is an equal correspondence between `atof` and [`strtof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof).

Comment: My suggestion is to use `sscanf` instead, e.g.:  `res = sscanf(str, "%f", &data);` and then check `if( res != 1)`

Comment: sorry what is the &data for?